# How to stop component re-render when redux store change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

When I dispatch an action from a child component that triggers a change in the Redux store, the whole tree gets re-render including the child component itself. How can I stop that?

For example ...

1- I'm listening for when a user clicks on a child component to expand it.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
<span onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>Expand</span>
```

2- Then if `expanded` is true I dispatch an action in `useEffect` ...

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (expanded) {
        dispatch(asyncGetItems())
    }
}, [expanded]);
```

3- Then inside the async dispatch it changes the redux store based on the returned data ...

```
export const getItems = (items: {}): AppActions => {
    return {
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: items,
    };
};

export const asyncGetItems = () => {
    return async (dispatch: any, getState: () => AppState) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await apiGetItems();
            dispatch(getItems(data));
        } catch (error) {
            handleResponseError(error);
        }
    };
};
```

Now, when I do that and change the data in the store the component gets re-rendered because its parents get re-rendered, how to stop that?

I tried to use `memo` like this, but it didn't work ...

```
export default memo(MyComponent);
```

And when I don't change anything in the store and just return the data like this ...

```
export const asyncGetItems = () => {
    return async (dispatch: any, getState: () => AppState) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await apiGetItems();
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            handleResponseError(error);
        }
    };
};
```

The component doesn't get re-rendered.

Comment: That's how redux work. You connect your components to the certain parts of the store so when the data is updated, the components can re-render. 
With memo components, you can set a specific comparison method to decide when to re-render. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo
Without seeing your whole code, I can't say much more.

Comment: @szczocik It says in the docs that "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs." what kind of bugs are they talking about?